# ssh'ing into github fails with "permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: github, ssh

I have an account on GitHub. I want to generate a SSH keypair on my local computer and add it to my GitHub account.

```
ssh-keygen -C "myemail@example.com" -f github
```

I get 2 keys: a public and private key.

I copy the content of github.pub to my GitHub account > Settings > SSH and GPG keys.

When I test the connection with `ssh -T git@github.com`, I get `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

When using `ssh -vT git@github.com`, I get the following output (redacted):

```
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
```

as you can see, my github key is not in the keys list.

What could be wrong? Am i using the wrong algorithm?

Comment: You have a _different_ key (or keys) loaded in your ssh auth agent (`ssh-add -l` should show it) and this is the key that SSH is trying to send to GitHub, rather than the key you actually intend to send. Try using `ssh -vT -i /path/to/GitHub/ssh/key git@github.com`. Does *that* work?

Comment: You can (instead of passing `-i` every time to ssh) configure your ssh, using `.ssh/config`, to use a specific key for a specific host (or matching patterns). This is an ssh configuration knob; it's not something specific to Git.